# How to vectorize a function with numpy so that it can be applied to a 3d array, given this function needs to access certain cells of the array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

I have a computation that in which I need go through items of a 3d numpy array and add them to the values in the second dimension of the array (skipping the values in that dimension). It is analogous to this canonical mimimal reproduction example:

```
import numpy as np


data = np.array([
    [[1, 1, 1], [10, 10, 10], [1, 1, 1]],
    [[2, 2, 2], [20, 20, 20], [2, 2, 2]],
    [[3, 3, 3], [30, 30, 30], [3, 3, 3]] ])


def process_data(const_idx, data, i, j, k):
    if const_idx != j:
        # PROBLEM: how can I access this value if this function is vectorized?
        value_to_add = data[i][const_idx][k]
        data[i][j][k] += value_to_add


const_idx = 1
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    for j in range(data.shape[1]):
        for k in range(data.shape[2]):
            process_data(const_idx, data, i, j, k)

print(data)
```

Where the expected output in this case would be:

```
[[[11 11 11]
  [10 10 10]
  [11 11 11]]

 [[22 22 22]
  [20 20 20]
  [22 22 22]]

 [[33 33 33]
  [30 30 30]
  [33 33 33]]]
```

The code above works but it is very slow for large arrays. I would like to vectorize this function.

My first stab is something like this:

```
def process_data(val, data, const_idx):
    # PROBLEM: How can I access this value given that I do not have access to the i / j / k coordinates val came from?
    value_to_add = ...
    
    # PROBLEM: I cannot make this check either since I dont know the j index being processed here
    if const_idx != j:
        return val + value_to_add
    else:
        return val

vfunc = np.vectorize(process_data)

result = vfunc(data, data, const_idx)

print(result)
```

How can I accomplish this, or is perhaps vectorization not the answer?

Comment: This seems similar to `data * [[1],[0],[1]] + data[:,1:2,:]`  I am not sure I understand correctly, although you could get the 10,20,30 as `data ** [[0],[1],[0]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const_idx` points to the index of the row which acts as an addition factor.
You can shortly perform the inplace addition on the needed dimensions with the following approach:

```
def add_by_idx(arr, idx):
    r = np.arange(arr.shape[1])  # row indices
    arr[:, r[r != idx], :] += arr[:, [idx], :]

add_by_idx(data, 1)
print(data)
```

---

```
[[[11 11 11]
  [10 10 10]
  [11 11 11]]

 [[22 22 22]
  [20 20 20]
  [22 22 22]]

 [[33 33 33]
  [30 30 30]
  [33 33 33]]]
```

Comment: Nice technique! I had changed things up to using numba's prange but this is much better - thanks!

Comment: @EdyBournem, you're welcome. +1 for the question

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach: add the row everywhere, then subtract it from the index:

```
def process_data(data, const_idx):
    to_add = data[:, const_idx, :].copy()
    data += to_add[:, None, :]
    data[:, const_idx] -= to_add

process_data(data, const_idx=1)
print(data)
```

Output:

```
[[[11 11 11]
  [10 10 10]
  [11 11 11]]

 [[22 22 22]
  [20 20 20]
  [22 22 22]]

 [[33 33 33]
  [30 30 30]
  [33 33 33]]]
```

Comment: Oh yes, very clever! This works and is very fast, thank you!